# Extended ACL not working with "host"-Attribute in Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, acl, packet-tracer

Here's the output (or the commands) which fails:

Normally it should work!

[image]

What's wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure about the `host` keyword problem, but you are first denying all traffic from the `10.0.0.0/8` network to anywhere. ACLs are evaluated in order, and they stop on a match. The second line will never be evaluated because the traffic will match the first line, and the ACL will stop.

Comment: that was the answer... it works now!

Comment: OK, I posted it as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are first denying all traffic from the 10.0.0.0/8 network to anywhere. ACLs are evaluated in order, and they stop on a match. The second line will never be evaluated because the traffic will match the first line, and the ACL will stop.